# How to draw border as I required around the image using CSS?

Tags: css

I have an image which already has a border around it. It's a part of the image. I want to draw the similar border around my image using CSS properties.

I tried the following CSS code...

`border-style:dashed;`

...but it's not drawing the border how I'd like it to. Below is the original image which has the border in the image itself...

[image: Image with border]

... and here is the image that I would like to add the border to using CSS

[image: Image without border]

Comment: What's wrong with [this](http://jsbin.com/irafan/2/edit) ?

Comment: @dystroy : I want the same border as of image 1 around the second image. But it should be using CSS properties.

Comment: do you want the corners omitted rather than filled in like the css example dystroy has supplied?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to also want a padding and a border color :

```
img {
  padding: 3px;
  border: grey dashed 2px;
}
```

Result :

[image]

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/irafan/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try border image

```
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
```